# Ataining an element of an array in numpy TypeError: cannot do slice indexing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

HI I am trying to get numbers from an array which returns

```
array([  72,  135,  193,  197,  203,  360,  374,  407.... 8158])
```

I then want to split my df based on the first element of the array e.g 72 
if I do

```
print(df.iloc[0:72 , :])
```

It works. However if I do

```
print(df.iloc[0:mask[0][:1] , :])
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [[72]] of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why does it do this? and How can I fix it so that I can make
dynamic?

```
df.iloc[0:72 , :]) 



x = np.array(df["Signal"])
mask = np.where(x == "Buy")

print(df.iloc[0:mask[0][:1] , :])
```

Comment: You probably get the error on the expression `mask[0][:1]`. How do you define the mask?

Comment: mask = np.where(x == "Buy")
print(mask[0][:1])

It works in that it gives the number I want although the issue could be that it returns [72]?

Comment: the error returns with these indexers [[72]]

Comment: Hm, I don't know if pandas's RangeIndex is compatible with numpy, but you can try `df.iloc[mask[0] , :]` or `df.iloc[mask, :]`

Comment: Cheers for your help I have solved it ther :1 seems to have been the error. df.iloc[0:mask[0][0] , :] Gets exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.iloc[0:mask[0][0] , :] Fixes the issue and returns the correct df data